# how to remove non character letter from name field using visual foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have not used Visual FoxPro for a while. Today, my ex-colleague asks me how to remove non character from name field, i.e. only a-z and A-Z are allowed. I remember I used a function called strstran to do it. I needed to define a variable contains a-z and A-Z. But I do not remember now. Does someone knows how to handle this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use the CHRTRAN() function.

```
FUNCTION GetAlphaCharacters
    LPARAMETERS tcExpressionSearched

    LOCAL lcAllowedCharacters
    m.lcAllowedCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    RETURN CHRTRAN(m.tcExpressionSearched, CHRTRAN(m.tcExpressionSearched, m.lcAllowedCharacters, ""), "")
ENDFUNC
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use ISALPHA(). This only looks at the left most position in the string but it's not case sensitive.

```
***This should work, but I haven't tested it.
myresults = ""
myvar = "MyText12"
FOR(i = 1 TO LEN(myvar))
   IF ISALPHA( SUBSTR(myvar, i, 1) )
     myresults = myresults +  SUBSTR(myvar, i, 1)
   ENDIF
ENDFOR
RETURN myresults
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but here is a function I wrote to clean out all non-printable ASCII characters from a character string.

```
    CLEAR

    * Contains ASCII characters 1 (SOH) and 2 (STX)
    cTest = "Garbage Data   "    

    ? cTest
    cTest = RemoveNonPrintableCharacters(cTest)
    ? cTest


    FUNCTION RemoveNonPrintableCharacters
        LPARAMETERS tcExpressionSearched

        cCleanExpression = tcExpressionSearched

        * Cleans out the first 32 ASCII characters, which are not printable
        FOR decCount = 0 TO 31
            cCleanExpression = CHRTRAN(m.cCleanExpression, CHR(decCount), "")    
        ENDFOR  

        * Also cleans out the non-printable DEL character (ASCII 127)
        cCleanExpression = CHRTRAN(m.cCleanExpression, CHR(127), "")

        * Return the clean string
        RETURN cCleanExpression
    ENDFUNC
```